# Whet I try to run Zenmap, the terminal show me this

Tags: python, nmap, kali-linux

Could not import the zenmapGUI.App module: 'No module named gtk'.
I checked in these directories:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

If you installed Zenmap in another directory, you may have to add the
modules directory to the PYTHONPATH environment variable.

------------------------------------------------resolved--------------------------------------------------------------------

```
$ mkdir -p ~/Downloads/zenmap
$ cd ~/Downloads/zenmap
$ wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-6_amd64.deb
$ wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/nmap/zenmap_7.80+dfsg1-1build1_all.deb
```

you have to unpackage those 2 /.deb and there you go

Comment: and what actually is in your PYTHONPATH variable?

Comment: Please take out the solution of your post and put that in an Answer. Solutions are not meant in to be part of a Question. See the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue when I tried to install zenmap. I had to install `pygtk2/` `py gobject-2/python-cairo`.

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygobject-2/python-gobject-2_2.28.6-14ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pycairo/python-cairo_1.16.2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Then install them use `dpkg -i <deb name>`.

Answer (score 3):

Update for Kali 2020v4 to solve that issue:

Run

```
sudo bash 
apt-get update 
apt-get upgrade
```

To clear any existing installation run:

```
apt remove zenmap
```

Then

```
apt-get install python-cairo  

apt --fix-broken install

apt-get install python-gobject-2

apt --fix-broken install

dpkg -i python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb 

dpkg -i zenmap_7.80-2_all.deb
```

Resources:

http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/

**To Install ZenMap for kali**

1. Update the repos: `sudo apt update`
2. Download latest package of zenmap, e.g. `wget https://nmap.org/dist/zenmap-7.80- 1.noarch.rpm`
3. Install alien: `sudo apt install alien -y`
4. Convert pack to deb Sintaxis: `sudo alien [RPM downloaded]`
5. Install Sintaxis: `sudo dpkg -i [DEB generated]`

Answer (score 0):

Same issue. I notice that in kali 2019-4, in the path `usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk` there are some `init` files, perhaps they are needed by the zenmap GUI.

Comment: solved, see the original post, i hope, its help you too

Comment: Thanks Oscarp. your fix works !!!! in addition, i had to install python-cairo and ndiff as dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Unstable Works.
Try this:

```
nix run -f channel:nixos-unstable nmap_graphical
```