# converting rpm files to debian error (package build failed)

Tags: linux, debian, rpm, nmap

after I install alien and
having zenmap in the download folder

when I run this command **alien zenmap-7.91-1.noarch.rpm** or any command related to it I get this error

package build failed. here's the log:

```
dh
dh: error:specify sequence to run
make:***[debian/rules:7:binary]Error 25
```

how do I fix this error? please help...

Answer (score 5):

First just to make sure you don't have any rpm problems run this command:

```
apt-get --fix-broken install
```

Then you may need these:

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb

wget http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygobject-2/python-gobject-2_2.28.6-14ubuntu1_amd64.deb

wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pycairo/python-cairo_1.16.2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb

dpkg -i python-gobject-2_2.28.6-14ubuntu1_amd64.deb 

dpkg -i python-cairo_1.16.2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb

dpkg -i python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

And after you have all that installed lets make sure our alien version is 8.90.

Remove alien:

```
apt-get remove alien
```

Download alien 8.90 version [here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/alien/alien_8.90_all.deb).

Install alien:

```
dpkg -i alien_8.90_all.deb
```

Now we will locate our zenmap file and run these commands:

```
sudo alien zenmap-7.91-1.noarch.rpm

sudo dpkg -i **YOUR-ZENMAP-FILE**.deb
```

If those commands run perfectly you can now run:

```
sudo zenmap
```

Et voilà! :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue installing Zenmap in kali linux.

> Package build failed. Here's the log:
> dh: error: specify a sequence to run make:
> *** [debian/rules:7: binary] Error 25

To solve this, I had to downgrade to Alien version 8.90, since I was using 8.95.3

There is some information online, and it's also detailed in the changelogs as well, explaining some changes performed on the latest alien updates and how they read the dh headers. Zenmap.rpm packages seem to be non-compilant with these updates.

I downgraded to a different Alien version to skip these dh verification changes.

To do so, I uninstalled the current alien version with

```
apt-get remove alien
```

Then, from https://pkgs.org/download/alien I downloaded Ubuntu Main amd64 Official alien_8.90_all.deb

```
installed with: dpkg -i alien_8.90_all.deb
```

Downloaded the latest Zenmap rpm version here
https://nmap.org/dist

and successfully converted rpm to deb running

```
alien zenmap-X.XX.noarch.rpm
```

Once the RPM was converted to .deb, you could run

```
dpkg -i zenmap-X.XX.noarch.deb
```

App would not open, running from CLI I figured that some python libs failed to load

> Could not import the zenmapGUI.App module: 'No module named gtk'. I
> checked in these directories:
> /usr/bin
> /usr/share/offsec-awae-wheels/colorama-0.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
> /usr/share/offsec-awae-wheels/pyOpenSSL-19.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
> ...

As suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64359059/whet-i-try-to-run-zenmap-the-terminal-show-me-this/65426605#65426605?newreg=de49f4935cdf428884124ac5597be5f2) I download the packages:

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygobject-2/python-gobject-2_2.28.6-14ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pycairo/python-cairo_1.16.2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Then installed with dpkg

```
dpkg -i python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb 
dpkg -i python-gobject-2_2.28.6-14ubuntu1_amd64.deb 
dpkg -i python-cairo_1.16.2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Now Zenmap is working beautifully.

Comment: can you explain again how to install zenmap after installing alien? somehow I miss this part in your explenation.

Comment: Just edited the post: Once Alien 8.90 is installed, you'll be able to convert the RPM to deb running alien zenmap-X.XX.noarch.rpm
Once the RPM was converted to .deb, you could run dpkg -i zenmap-X.XX.noarch.deb to install

Answer (score 1):

You can install the package directly using `-i` option:

```
sudo alien -i zenmap-7.91-1.noarch.rpm
```

Also you can use `fpm` to convert an `rpm` to `deb`, to install it:

```
sudo apt install ruby ruby-dev rubygems build-essential
sudo gem install --no-document fpm
```

To convert:

```
fpm -s rpm -t deb zenmap-7.91-1.noarch.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same exact issue, I was using

```
alien -i package.rpm
```

I believe this error occurred because of an update to the bullseye version from `bullseye/main alien all 8.95+nmu1` to `bullseye/main alien all 8.95.3`. Updating Debian preferences to install alien from buster with version `buster/main alien all 8.95` fixed the issue for me! Hope this helps!